# Accessing OpenSSL's SMIME functions from Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, openssl

What's the proper way to access OpenSSL's SMIME functions from Python3? Failing that, is there any obvious way to access SMIME from Python3? Right now I'm going to be using the "openssl" command as a subprocess.

Comment: Seems similar to [Non-detached PKCS#7 SHA1+RSA signature without M2Crypto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32020356/non-detached-pkcs7-sha1rsa-signature-without-m2crypto)